# Ensembles - How to support plists with Dropbox?

Tags: ios, plist, ensembles

We have been testing Ensembles and developing a migration strategy from our current sync method.  We use plists extensively to manage app settings which work fine with iCloud, if devices are using the same iCloud Account.

Question: When using Dropbox and other non iCloud backends is there a recommended strategy for handling plists or must they simply be converted to Core Data?

Awesome and well documented product. Great Job!

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are syncing with Ensembles, I would simply create an entity called "Settings", give it a fixed unique identifier so that Ensembles uses the same settings across devices, and then make a single object with that entity. The entity should have a data property where you can serialize the plist.